# Hyperledger Fabric External builder Failed to generate a Dockerfile: Unknown chaincodeType: EXTERNAL

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, chaincode

```
peer lifecycle chaincode install ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-external/asset-transfer-basic-external.tgz
```

Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': could not build chaincode: docker build failed: platform builder failed: Failed to generate a Dockerfile: Unknown chaincodeType: EXTERNAL

Comment: Hey did you resolve this Error?!

Answer (score 0):

Provide the required permissions of scripts in the bin (build, release, detect) directory.

```
chmod 777 -R bin/
```

And also make sure to map the chaincode directory properly

**core.yaml**

```
externalBuilders: 
    # This path has to be mapped to peer containers with a local chaincode directory
    - path: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/external-builder
      name: chaincode-external-builder
      propagateEnvironment:
         - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE
         - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE
         - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
....
  volumes:
    # external builder chaincode path (local/path:container/path)
    - ../chaincode:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/external-builder
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because for one reason or another your external builder is not being executed at all and that causes the peer to try to install the chaincode by the traditional way. For that part of the code type `external` is not supported, hence the error.

In my case the mistake was that my `core.yaml` was misformatted because the `externalBuilders` definition was indented too much to right so it wasn't defined under `chaincode` definition anymore. And because in reality the external builder wasn't defined at all because of the misformatting it couldn't be executed and then I got exactly the same error.

So, be careful how you format your yaml files.